# chrome, firefox render differently between operating systems

Tags: browser

Why do Chrome and firefox (I haven't tried safari) render differently between chrome and firefox between Ubuntu and Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The version numbers could be different.
- Fonts etc could be different.
- Non-pixel unit calculations could be different.
- User settings could be different.

What exactly are the differences? Do you have some screenshots?

Comment: I'm happy that you accepted the answer, but for the benefit of other readers, could you perhaps elaborate on the problem and point out the solution?

Comment: I didn't realize that the font was causing the problem. The default font was different so I just set it in the body tag.